# Find corresponding symbol for gene used in Seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, gene, seurat

I have a Seurat object

```
> pbmc
An object of class Seurat 
48608 features across 11709 samples within 2 assays 
Active assay: SCT (22220 features, 3000 variable features)
 1 other assay present: RNA
 2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, umap
>
```

I want to plot TCRVδ2

```
> FeaturePlot(pbmc,"TCRVδ2")
Error: None of the requested features were found: TCRVδ2 in slot data
In addition: Warning message:
In FetchData(object = object, vars = c(dims, "ident", features),  :
  The following requested variables were not found: TCRVδ2
>
```

This data base is about human TCR genes

https://www.genenames.org/data/genegroup/#!/group/370

But I even can not find this gene here

Do you know what is the corresponding symbol for this gene used in Seurat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TCRVδ2` is not a gene, but it defines a specific subset of gamma-delta TCRs. You can look at `TRDC` (delta chain) and `TRGC1` and `TRGC2` (gamma chains). `TCRVδ2` should have the combo `TRDC-TRGC1`, while `TCRVδ1` should express `TRDC-TRGC2`. You may need to increase the resolution of your clustering, to avoid clustering the gamma-delta T cells with the NK cells.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question about gene symbols. CD45 is corresponding to PTPRC butler most of CD genes I can not find the corresponding official gene symbols. Please, do you know how I can find corresponding gene symbols for CD genes?